# How can I get the values from two list a time

Tags: python, list, function, parameter-passing

I have two Lists: one contains filenames and the other timestamps for the corresponding file name.

This is my code:

```
for afile in filelist:
    for times in timestamps:
        self.importFiles(afile,times)
```

But this code will call the function prints different timestamp for same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using nested for loop. So for each file name, all timestamps will be printed. Use a single for loop.

```
length = len(filelist)
for i in range(length):
   self.importFiles(filelist[i],timestamps[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Pythonic way, using [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
for afile, timestamp in zip(filelist, timestamps):
    self.importFiles(afile,timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, file in enumerate(filelist):
    self.importFiles(file,timestamps[i])
```

This will result in i being the index and file the corresponding entry of filelist.